# SOLR query finding less than 7 charactes

Tags: arrays, solr

I have SOLR data I am querying.  One of the fields is an array which looks like this (there are many records, this is just the first):

```
    "office_address_line1": [
      "Po",
      "317 S Drexel Blvd #330",
      "35 Village Plaza",
      "2215 Carol Ave",
      "35 Drexel BLVD",
      "158 Connecticut Ave"
    ]
  }
```

Notice that one line is just "Po".  There are other entries that have values like "Po Box 7" and "Po Box 70" etc.

first if I want to find Po exactly I do **office_address_line1:Po** but instead of exact matches it gets everything starting with Po.  If I do **office_address_line1:"Po Box 7"** however, it will get only the 7 and not the 70.

First I want to figure out why this is.  But more importantly I need to find addresses less than 7 character.  I try all sorts of things like /.{6}/ or /.{1,7}/ and /^.{1,7}$/ and even !office_address_line1:/.{7,100}/ but nothing returns what I want. Specifying ranges returns things in, and out of, that range.

So I am wondering first why **office_address_line1:"Po"** does not return just that where it is an exact match.  Secondly, I wonder why my range queries are not returning what I want.  I must have read every thing that Google came up with for SOLR queries.

One question I have.  Since it is an array of Strings, does the query have to match each line in the array?  Otherwise, what kind of query should I do?  If worse comes to worst as I said there should be addresses with just "Po" but that query did not work either.

Comment: What is the type of the field `office_address_line1`? If it's not a string field, it's being tokenized and split into separate tokens (for example by whitespace), where each token will be considered for a match.

Comment: Then the content will be split into separate tokens, and each token will be matched by itself. So "po" will match "po" as a separate token (i.e. "po box", "box po", etc., while "post office" will not match, since it'll consist of two tokens, post and office. If you want to keep the whole string unchanced, use a `string` field.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have edit access to the schema ;-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since text is your field type so above field is getting tokenized on whitespace.
So your query `office_address_line1:"Po"` will return all documets having a token "Po".
Try `office_address_line1:/.{1,7}./` for field having at length less then 7. But for this query to work your office_address_line1 field should be indexed as string (as a single token).

You can use solr `<copyfield>` tag to make a copy of this field as string and run your rangequery on that copied field.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no control over the schema.  Is there a way to do the copyfield from an SOLR query?

Comment: The copyField is done when a document is indexed, so it is before the index analyzer or query analyzer.So you can not copyfield from solr query.

Comment: Looks like part of the query I will have to do with SQL to get the correct addresses, and then continue with SOLR